# In C, Passing a character pointer to a function and make it to point somewhere, Is it WRONG?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I was trying to modify the `month_day` program in K&R's C book. The following code is the K&R's `month_day` function (page 111, Section 5.7)

```
void month_day(int year, int yearday, int *pmonth, int *pday){...}
```

If it is called in `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    int month = 0, day = 0;
    month_day(1996, 290, &month, &day);
}
```

then `month` is 10 and `day` is 16. So It's OK. But I want to make month is a string, I need `month` to be "OCT".
So I declared a pointer array of names of months,

```
char *monthnames[0] = {
    "Illegal Month",
    "JAN", "FEB", "MAR",
    "APR", "MAY", "JUN",
    "JUL", "AUG", "SEP",
    "OCT", "NOV", "DEC",
}; // "Illegal Month" is there to adjust index numbers to months. So "JAN"
   // is monthnames[1] (It'll be monthnames[0] otherwise).
```

Then I change `month_day`,

```
char daytab[2][13] = {
    {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
    {0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
};

void month_day(int year, int yearday, char *pmonth, int *pday)
{
    int leap, i;
    char *p;

    leap = (year % 4) == 0 && (year % 100) != 0 || (year % 400) == 0;

    p = &daytab[leap][1];

    for (i = 1; yearday >= *p; i++) {
        yearday -= *p;
        p++;
    }

   *pday = yearday;
   pmonth = monthnames[i]; // I expect pmonth to be pointed to i-th String in monthnames[].

}
```

In `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    char *month;
    int day;

    month_day(1996, 290, month, &day); // I expect month is pointed to "OCT" & day is 16. 
    printf("1996-%s-%d", month, day);
}
```

I could compile it without errors.
But when I run it it gives me that ".exe  has stopped working" error in windows.
Could someone please explain me why?
And tell me how to do it?

Comment: Use GDB or add print statements to see where your code is breaking.

Comment: I'm not a C expert, but your code could be breaking because you try to print `month`, but there is no terminating NULL character, so it screws up.

Comment: @ameyCU Why wouldn't a `char` be able to hold `31`?

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `char *monthnames[13]` instead of `char *monthnames[0]`?

Comment: @gragas Yeah , made a mistake , but it will print the corresponding charracter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked:

> In C, Passing a character pointer to a function and make it to point somewhere, Is it WRONG?

It is not wrong. It is, sometimes, counter to what a user expects.

Try something small.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char global_string[] = "abcd";
void test_function(char* s)
{
   s = global_string;
}

int main()
{
   char* s = NULL;
   test_function(s);
   if ( s == NULL )
   {
      printf("s is still same\n";
   }
}
```

In this program, the value of `s` is changed in `test_function` but it has no effect on the value of `s` in `main`. In `main`, the value of `s` is still `NULL`. If you expected the value of `s` to be changed in `main`, then your function is not doing what you expected. Is it wrong? No it is not. Your expectation is not correct.

If you want the value of `s` to be changed in `main`, there are several techniques. I am not sure this is the right place to expound on them.

Comment: Yeah Thank you I got it, so  "char *pmonth" should be "char **pmonth" and "pmonth = monthnames[i]" should be "*month = monthnames[i]".

Comment: That's correct. It should be called with `&month` instead of `month`.

Answer (score 2):

You are emulating *pass by reference* by passing a pointer to `day`, you need to do the same for `month` as well, i.e. pass a pointer to the pointer.